# GCE firewall with Source Tags

Tags: networking, firewall, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

1. Created an instance in GCE, tagged 'tagA'
2. Created firewall rule: `tcp:12345`, source tag `tagA`, target tag `tagA`
3. On the instance executed: `nc -l 0.0.0.0 -p 12345`

> netstat -an | grep 12345
>
> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:12345           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN

4. Trying to connect internal:
   `nc -v internal.ip 12345` => 12345 (?) open
5. Trying to connect external:
   `nc -v external.ip 12345` => 12345 (?) : Connection refused

According to GCE manual:

> sourceTags
> [Required if sourceRanges is not specified] If the source is within this network and has one of the specified tags, the connection will be accepted. If both sourceRanges and sourceTags are specified, an inbound connection is allowed if either the range or the tag of the source matches sourceRanges or sourceTags.

Can anyone explain why port on external IP is not available with this firewall rule?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Target and source tags are only available for internal use only if no network is specified on the rule, as you mentioned in your question `If both sourceRanges and sourceTags are specified, an inbound connection is allowed if either the range or the tag of the source matches sourceRanges or sourceTags.` So in order to make it secure, allow your local network IP range (where you are trying to connect from) only on the firewall.

Comment: Do I get it right, it is NOT possible to allow access on external IP using source tags? I have a bunch of hosts within same network that need to talk on external ip and it's pain to configure them individually.

Comment: You've got it right. This is how it is on all firewalls. You can add network ranges instead of adding single IPs (of course if you trust the range).